# Why is the first term of this series 1 and not 0? (I have the answer but don't understand how to get there)

Tags: polynomials, summation

$$s=\sum_{i=0}^4 b_i(y)u^i$$

I'm reading a paper where someone has provided the expression above, a fourth-order power series in y and u. Each term is expanded and the first term is

$$b_0(y) = 1$$

I don't understand how it isn't zero because s should be zero when u is zero for physical reasons.

When I use Python's curve_fit to solve this, I get the right answer--s is $0$ when u is $0$.  It has been a long time since I learned about summation and there's something I'm not understanding about what's going on.  If anyone could please direct me, I would be grateful.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thank you for your help!  Wait, it's as simple as u^0 = 1?  (u is never 0).  Please provide an answer so I can give you credit.  Very embarrassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ is not $0$, then $u^0=1$. So the "first" (or rather "zeroth") term of that sum is $b_0(y)$.